# How do I pass arguments to Manim Community via command line?

Tags: python, manim

Manim Renders scene(s) to an output file with,

```
manim [OPTIONS] FILE [SCENES]
```

I didn't find a way to pass arguments to Manim Community after checking [A list of all CLI flags](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/configuration.html#a-list-of-all-cli-flags).

How can I pass arguments to Manim Community via the command line? Or further, is there a way to run a manim class without using command line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Which arguments do you want to pass? What's wrong with the provided example `manim -qm file.py SceneOne` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry for the late reply. I'd like to pass custom arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your first question regarding arguments -- do you mean custom arguments? We don't have support for that yet.

However, you can definitely render scenes from your Python script directly by using a snippet like this:

```
with tempconfig({"quality": "medium_quality", "preview": True}):
    scene = YourSceneClass()
    scene.render()
```

This is also useful for debugging Manim scenes.